# How to partition a problem into smaller understandable portions?

Tags: partitioning, decomposition

I'm not sure if it's possible to give general advice on this topic, but please try. It's hard to explain my case because it's too complex to explain. And that's exactly the problem.

I seem to constantly stumble on a situation where I try to design some part of my project, but it has so many things to take into consideration that I'm unable to get a grasp of it.

Are there any general tips or advice on how to look at my system in smaller pieces at a time? How to find smaller portions that could be designed separately on their own?

Comment: Added tag "decomposition". That, and factoring, are formal names for what you're trying to do. Searching on those terms might give you some places to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your key goals are:

- **High cohesion**: Code (methods, fields, classes) within one piece/module/partition should interact intensively; it should *make sense* for these elements to know about each other. If you find that some of them don't interact much with the rest, they probably belong somwhere else or should form their own partition. If you find code outside interacting intensively with the partition and knowing too much about its inner workings, it probably belongs inside. The typical example is found in OO code written in procedural style, with "dumb" data objects and "manager" code that operates on them but should really be part of the data objects.
- **Loose coupling**: Interaction *between* pieces/modules/partitions should only happen through narrow, well-defined, well-documented APIs. Try to identify such APIs and see what code is needed to implement them and what code will use them.

Comment: I kind of knew this already, but I don't know much about OO so I haven't really figured these out yet.

Answer (score 4):

Create a glossary.

In other words, identify the terms that are meaningful to the project domain — not from the programmer's point of view, but from a user's, who is familiar with the subject matter.

Then define the terms as *precisely* and *discretely* as you can.  A good definition in this form can serve as a kind of pseudocode.

Since you have not identified even the domain of your problem, I'll choose a random example.  In a civilian personnel system, you might have terms like:

- **billet**: a term of service (from start date to end date) at a particular grade and step
- **employee**: a series of billets associated with a particular SSN
- **grade and step**: row and column in the federal general schedule

And so on.  This isn't to identify functional units, as it sounds like you are trying to do, but it's a good preparatory step before doing so, so that you can express your functional steps in well-defined terms.

Comment: Not really what I was looking for, but still a very good advice.

Answer (score 2):

It's useful to approach problem decomposition both top-down and bottom-up.

If you're having trouble splitting a big problem into two or more smaller problems, try to think of the smallest possible problems that will need to be solved.  Once those are handled, you may start to see ways to combine them into larger problems as you approach your original large problem.

Answer (score 1):

When I find myself copying and pasting chunks of code with minimal adjustments I realize that's a "partition" and then create a class, method, function, or whatever.

Actually, the whole object oriented approach is what it's all about.  Try thinking of your application as tangible things that do stuff.  Write pseudo code describing what the things are and what they do, I find lots of "partitions" this way.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a try, kind of wild guess.

People usually underestimate how long it will take them to do the work. If your project is large, then most likely you'll need several people to work on it, so you can try planning with that in mind. Now a person can be expected to hold just one area in the head, so you'll need to explain to him exactly what kind of task he's supposed to do.

So I'd say you should try to write a job description that should encompass as much as possible for one person to seriously concentrate on. Repeat, until you have broken your project into parts you wanted to. As a benefit, you're ready to assemble your team. But if you find out the parts are small, maybe you'll still be able to do it yourself.